# Watermark adding in R

Tags: r

I am using `magick` library in R. I want to add watermark on some pictures.

I used `image_annotate`function as below.

```
img <- image_read("C:\\Users\\Maydin\\Desktop\\manzara.png")
image_annotate(img, "my watermark", gravity = "northwest", location = "+200+275",
               degrees = -30, size =50, font = NULL, color = "transparent",
               strokecolor = "gray90", boxcolor = NULL)
```

At the end, the output looks like this;

[image]

However, what I want to have is something like this ,

[image]

Is that doable in `magick` in `R`?

Comment: could you provide the input photo?

Comment: @Hack-R I upload it on this link :  https://imgur.com/0qgo1ML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For instance, this

```
download.file("https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X5To.png", tf<-tempfile(fileext = ".png"), mode="wb")
library(magick)
img <- image_read(tf)
library(extrafont)
truetype_path <- paste0("@", subset(fonttable(), FullName=="Matura MT Script Capitals", fontfile)[1,])
image_annotate(img, "my watermark", gravity = "northwest", location = "+70+220",
               degrees = -30, size = 80, font = truetype_path, color = "#FFFFFF66",
               strokecolor = NULL, boxcolor = NULL)
```

gives this image:

[image]

I.e., choose a nice font like maybe *Matura MT Script Capitals*, tell `image_annotate` where to find it on your harddrive, adjust the opacity in the `color` argument - et voila. The font does not drop a shadow or show a relief, but maybe you can emulate this by plotting the text two times, the dark shadow one with a little offset to the other light one.

Comment: It is not the same as my aim but absolutely much better than my work :) .Thank you... I tried it, and it worked well! But, I did not understand the opacity adjustment you told about. Are you trying to say choosing a color from the palette like stated on this link : http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~tzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf ? Or Does there exist any opacity adjustment way that I don't know?

Comment: @maydin The color code is RGBA (red green blue alpha), each one ranging from 0 to 255 (00 to FF in hexadecimal notation). So `color = "#FFFFFF11", strokecolor = "#FFFFFF22"` gives you white with high transparency for the fill color, and a little less transparency for the stroke color.

Comment: Ok. The numbers at the end are for setting the opacity..I didn’t know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

@lukA nicely demonstrates a solution using **extrafonts** package with **magick** package, but it looks like you can refer to the font by name within `image_annotate()` without the clever lookup of the full path. Use `extrafonts::fonttable()` to find the name.

```
library(extrafonts)
library(magick)
#download original example file
download.file("https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X5To.png", tf<-tempfile(fileext = ".png"), mode="wb")
img <- image_read(tf)
 
#Use stroke to create an outline of the text with 50% alpha  
 magick::image_annotate(img, "Preview", location = "+100+175", degrees = -30, size=75, weight=700, font = "MonotypeCorsiva" , color = "transparent",
    strokecolor = "#00000050",  boxcolor = NULL)
```

[image: Demonstrates annotating image with magick package.]