# How to insert a watermark in a wordcloud2 outputs

Tags: r, watermark, wordcloud2

I like to personalize my graphics with watermark in the background JPG or PNG image.
I use wordcloud2, RStudio, and the text can be any. Using wordcloud1 help is also welcome.

If wordcloud2 can not be used as i noticed with Letter, image, ..., wordcloud1 may be an interesting solution.

```
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"), native=TRUE)

library(wordcloud2)
wordcloud2(data = demoFreq)
```

For example use the R logo as watermark I expect the watermark "R" appears in the background of the wordcloud.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46667578/watermark-adding-in-r

Comment: Thank you Jay.sf for the link above. I did run the code and had the following error : > truetype_path <- paste0("@", subset(fonttable(), FullName=="Matura MT Script Capitals", fontfile)[1,])
Error in eval(e, x, parent.frame()) : object 'FullName' not found. I thought that @ should be replaced with the path to fonts in C:/WINDOW/FONTS but no is not that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to achieve the task. When you use `wordcloud2()`, there is an argument that you can specify background color (i.e., `backgroundColor`). I thought `backgroundColor = "transparent"` would be the way to go. But it seems that output files have white color in background. (I may be doing something wrong. If so, please correct me.) So I ended up using GIMP to edit wordclouds. You can even overlay wordcloud on top of a background image with the software. But, I chose to use the `magick` package to use R. For making background color transparent, see [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5446/making-the-background-of-an-image-transparent-in-gimp). The question contains all steps you need to go through.

Once the wordcloud is ready, you can run codes below. I hope this helps you.

```
library(magick)

# Import images
words <- image_read("my_wordcloud.png")
logo <- image_read("R.svg")

# Stack layers
img <- c(logo, words)
img <- image_scale(img, "500x500")
image_info(img)

# combine the layers into a single image 
foo <- image_flatten(img)

# Save the image
image_write(foo, path = "so.png", format = "png")
```

[image]